# Como puedo Hacer un select con Linq para sacar filas

Tags: asp.net, linq

AQUI MUESTRO MI CODIGO LINQ

```
    //select para mostrar nombres en ver,delete  
public ComprarBloqueosBusqueda BuscaPorNombre(int? id )
        {
            ComprarBloqueosBusqueda vCOMBLO_Comprar = new ComprarBloqueosBusqueda();
            var query2 = (from BloExc in contexto.BloqueoExcursion                         
                         /* haciendo join para Comprar bloqeueoExcursion*/
                          join Exc in contexto.Excursion
                          on BloExc.BLE_ExcursionId equals Exc.ExcursionesId

                      where                                                      

                    //igualando el ID de BloqueoExcursion
                       Exc.ExcursionesId == BloExc.BLE_ExcursionId &&
                       BloExc.BLE_BloqueoID == id &&

                      select new
                      {
                        //haciendo select para bloqueo excursion                                
                          BLE_ExcursionId = BloExc.BLE_ExcursionId,
                          EXC_Nombre = Exc.EXC_Nombre,

                      }); //.Take(1000);

        var lComBloquepsNom = query2.ToList();
        foreach (var datos in lComBloquepsNom)
        {
            //agregando los datos de bloqueoexcursiones para comprar
            vCOMBLO_Comprar.BLE_ExcursionId = datos.BLE_ExcursionId;
            vCOMBLO_Comprar.excursiones = datos.EXC_Nombre;
           // vCOMBLO_Comprar.BLE_BloqueoID = datos.BLE_BloqueoID;

        }
        return vCOMBLO_Comprar;
    }
    // fin select para sacar ver, delete
```

//////////////AQUI MUESTRO MI CODIGO DE Controlador/////////////////

```
    public ActionResult Comprar(int? id)
    {
        CompraBloViewModel combloqueosVM = new CompraBloViewModel();
        ComprarBloqueosBusqueda comprarbloqueos = combloqueosVM.BuscaPorNombre(id);
        return View(comprarbloqueos);
    }
```

/////////////////////////////////////
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

introducir la descripción de [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]la imagen aquí

---

En mi vista quiero que me salga varios excuriones, pero en mi caso tengo solo unos excursiones, solamente me sale un excursiones, como puedo hacer select con linq para que me salga varios excursiones.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres varios resultados debes usar una lista generica que contenga el listado de objetos que desees retornar, y en cada iteración del foreach debes adicionar a la lista una nueva instancia del objeto  ComprarBloqueosBusqueda en este caso.

```
public List<ComprarBloqueosBusqueda> BuscaPorNombre(int? id ) 
{ 
    var vCOMBLO_Comprar = new List<ComprarBloqueosBusqueda>(); 

    var query2 = (from BloExc in contexto.BloqueoExcursion
    join Exc in contexto.Excursion on BloExc.BLE_ExcursionId equals Exc.ExcursionesId
    where Exc.ExcursionesId == BloExc.BLE_ExcursionId && BloExc.BLE_BloqueoID == id
    select new
                  {
                    //haciendo select para bloqueo excursion                                
                      BLE_ExcursionId = BloExc.BLE_ExcursionId,
                      EXC_Nombre = Exc.EXC_Nombre,
                  }); //.Take(1000);

    var lComBloquepsNom = query2.ToList();
    foreach (var datos in lComBloquepsNom)
    {
        vCOMBLO_Comprar.Add( new ComprarBloqueosBusqueda 
            {
                BLE_ExcursionId = datos.BLE_ExcursionId,
                excursiones = datos.EXC_Nombre 
            } );
    }
    return vCOMBLO_Comprar;
}
// fin select para sacar ver, delete
```

Comment: Un ejemplo me puedes mostrar por favor con esto ya me pase como una semana.